# Best way to make N-number of api calls in Angular 9 synchronously (i.e) sequentially

Tags: angular, typescript, http, promise, rxjs

I am having a service method to API call in below way:-

```
getUsers(id){
  return this.http.get(`${env.apiURL}/id`)
}
```

Now I need to call this method for a list of users present in an Array which is like:-

```
userId=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I need to get all the API call results and printed for that I made use of fork-join in below way:-

```
    let user1= this.http.get(baseurl+'users/userId[1]');
    let user2= this.http.get(baseurl+'users/userId[2]');//In the similar way I have 10 values

    forkJoin([user1, user2]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our user1
      // results[1] is our user2
    });
```

But in the above way I was unable to make API calls Sequentially i.e Synchronously all API calls went parallelly which is not my use case.

Is there any best way to make the above n(variable number of users) API calls sequentially?
**Note**:-I am also having another scenario to keep a delay of 500ms after every API calls is it possible.I tried using

```
pipe(throttletime(500)) //this i added after forkJoin operation
```

But All of the API calls went at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this task.  Here are a couple of them:

---

Method 1:

```
  users$ = from(this.userIds).pipe(
    concatMap(id => this.getUser(id)),
    take(this.userIds.length),
    toArray()
  );
```

Steps:

- [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) - creates observable that emits each array element individually
- [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) - maps the ID to an observable, subscribes to it, and emits the results.  will only allow a single `getUser(id)` subscription at a time (synchronously)
- [`take`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) - instructs our stream how many values to take before completing
- [`toArray`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray) - collects emissions and emits them as an array upon completion

---

Method 2:

```
  users$ = from(this.userIds).pipe(
    concatMap(id => this.getUser(id)),
    scan((all: User[], user) => ([...all, user]), []),
  );
```

Steps:

- `from`
- `concatMap`
- [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) - accumulate emissions into a single array. emits every time a new value is received

---

Either of these should work fine, but there is a difference in behavior.  Method #1 will emit only one time, after all individual calls have completed.  Method #2 will emit once for every emission.  (*If only a single emission is desired, [`reduce`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/reduce) could be used instead*)

Check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66540889?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to see the differences in output between the two methods.

Comment: Why not use `reduce` operator instead of `toArray` in method 1?

Comment: @MichaelD - I mentioned `reduce` in the sub-text of Method 2.  Sure it could be done, but I think `toArray()` is much simpler to read.  I wouldn't be surprised if under the hood `toArray` was just a specific use case of `reduce` :-)

Comment: That's exactly what [it is](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/operators/toArray.ts#L44).

Comment: ha ha... nice! I was too lazy to look it up. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using `concatmap` operator to make requests in a specific order.
please refer => https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap

Comment: I want to iterate over a array and then make an api call for every iteration is iteration possible using concat Map